# bluetoothLE universal sample value changed

Tags: uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am currently using the windows-universal-samples-bluetoothle for my final year project. I'm facing one problem. I am connecting this to my rfduino to capture my value. I can manually capture my data whenever I press the "read" button. But how do I press the "read" button one time and it actually auto update the value ?

for example, I have setup my rfduino with mpu6050. so the angles will change will change when I move the mpu6050. I can capture this data everytime I press "read" on my UWP. Now I want to make it update automatically. how do I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Bluetooth LE Advertisements allow your device to constantly beacon out a specific payload, called an advertisement. This advertisement can be seen by any nearby Bluetooth LE capable device, if they are set up to listen for this specific advertisment. If your rfduino supports Bluetooth LE Advertisement. You could create `BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher` to receive `Advertisement` automatically.

```
BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher();
watcher.Received += OnAdvertisementReceived;
watcher.Start();

private async void OnAdvertisementReceived(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    // Do whatever you want with the advertisement
}
```

For more detail you could refer [**Bluetooth LE Advertisements**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/ble-beacon) official docuemnt and this is [code sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BluetoothAdvertisement).